# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/com.android.contacts/data/1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, contacts

> I picked contact from phone contacts list and also found the name and phone number of particular person but when I want to Send the contact to Firebase like WhatsApp than i could not find the actual path to upload the contacts that's why I found the above Exception...

**Using the code for pick Contacts**

```
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACT = 234;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_CONTACT = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    };

int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ChatActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                ChatActivity.this,
                    PERMISSIONS_CONTACT,
                    REQUEST_READ_CONTACT
                        );
        }else{
            // we already have permission, lets go ahead and call camera intent
            Intent contactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactIntent, PHONE_NUMBER_REQUEST);
        }
```

**onActivityResult Code:**

```
if (requestCode==4){
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                String phoneNo = null;
                String name = null;
                Uri uri2=data.getData();
                String uri = String.valueOf(data.getData());
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri2, null, null, null, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
                    name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);

                    UploadContactsToFireBase(uri,name,phoneNo);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                cursor.close();
            }
```

**UploadContactsToFireBase:**

```
void UploadContactsToFireBase(String contactsPath, final String contactName, final String phoneNumber ){

        final Dialogs loader=new Dialogs(this);
        loader.showDialog(Dialogs.DIALOG_CENTERED);
        final String name = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();
        StorageReference filePath = documentsStorageReference.child(name+"_contacts");
        final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(contactsPath));
        UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putFile(uri);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                loader.dismiss();
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Download Url: "+downloadUrl,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel(downloadUrl.toString(),contactName,phoneNumber);

                ChatMessage newMessage = new ChatMessage(null,mCurrentUserId,mRecipientId,
                        null,null,Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()+"",null,null,null,contactModel);
                messageChatDatabase.push().setValue(newMessage);
            }
        });

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"onFailure sendFileFirebase "+e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

**Error:**

```
10-31 13:45:33.632 11777-15995/com.tecorb.chatapp E/StorageException: /content:/com.android.contacts/data/1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                      java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/com.android.contacts/data/1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                          at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
                                                                          at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                                          at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:644)
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.tecorb.chatapp.ui.ChatActivity.uploadContacts(ChatActivity.java:927)
                                                                          at com.tecorb.chatapp.ui.ChatActivity.onActivityResult(ChatActivity.java:639)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                       Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                          at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                          at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                          at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
                                                                          at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                                          at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:644) 
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source) 
                                                                          at com.tecorb.chatapp.ui.ChatActivity.uploadContacts(ChatActivity.java:927) 
                                                                          at com.tecorb.chatapp.ui.ChatActivity.onActivityResult(ChatActivity.java:639) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: Yes.. That is not a file path. Its a content scheme if it starts with content://.

Comment: `why I found the above Exception...`. Please do not refer to the subject. Put all info in the post.

Comment: Further you should have started with the intent to choose from contacts.

Comment: **Ok sir i am using the code to pick contacts**
Intent contactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(contactIntent, PHONE_NUMBER_REQUEST);

Comment: Do not put code in comments. Put it at the start of your post. Begin with the begin.

Comment: and how can i found the actual path sir..?

Comment: Please write a decent post first.

Comment: Done sir, and found the exception above Exception on like **UploadTask** inside UploadContactsToFireBase method

Comment: You are still referring to the subject. That is not done! Put all info in the body of your post. Further there are no questions in your post.

Comment: sir i define completely the problem where i found and when i am upload the documents uploaded successfully,  but here i could not found the file path so please help sir ..

Comment: Thete is no file path. There is no file. So dont try to find one.